# How can i get subdomain and filename in .htaccess?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, atk4

Using the following htaccess code i am only getting the filename.

But what i need is that if user visits a url

```
http://TEMPLATE.domain.com/FILENAME.html
```

then i get it as

```
index.php?page=site/FILENAME&skin=TEMPLATE
```

### .htaccess code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -indexes
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}    ^([a-z0-9]+)\.domain\.com$  [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ([a-z0-9]+).html$                   [NC]
RewriteRule ^[^.]*.html$    index.php?page=site/%1&skin=%2      [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your rule to:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z0-9]+)\.domain\.com$  [NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+).html$ index.php?page=site/$1&skin=%1 [L,NC]
```

Specifically, you're backreference is being lost, so you need to create one backreference for your previous `RewriteCond` (via **%1**) and then one against the rule's regex, which is backreferenced via **$1**.

Comment: I also want to skip rewrite if subdomain is `empty` or `www.` how do i do that ?

Comment: Answer:

by adding following two lines on top of ReWriteCond
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]

Comment: @QambarRaza Add this condition above the one that's already there: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]`